# In flutter in_app_purchase how to redeem code form outside the app and connect that to user specific id?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

We have implemented in_app_purchase and it's working fine but lets say i have a promo code link which can be used outside the app and someone redeem the code and they are subscribed with their apple or google account now what logic should we implement to link the user who has applied the promo code outside the app to the userid of the app.

I have tried server notification but failed to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to consider here: a legal one and a technical one.

On the legal side, you have to make sure not to violate any constraints that Apple or Google have imposed on redeeming promo codes outside your app. This is especially important, if those promo codes have been sold outside of the official app stores (see [Apple Payment Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments) and [Google Payment Policies](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738)).

The technical aspect depends a lot on your general setup. What happens, when the promo code is redeemed outside your app? Do you store that information somewhere on a server? If so, the approach could be to get that information from inside your app and then implement your own custom business logic, that provides the same privileges to the user as it would provide those privileges to an officially subscribed user.